# App Testing Fails because target/bundle is not properly set of ios app, in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My project was renamed once from "Jiffy" to "Choice Finx-Jiffy" and was doen improperly the app runs and installs and works properly but while performing UITests it installs another blank app with the name Jiffy next to the actual app, and thus I am unable to do any kind of testing.
Any suggestions and solutions are welcome.

[image: Blank App Next to Actual App]

Here is my entire project structure:
[image]

Tried renaming the project with different methods nothing seems to work.